# Aligning vue components with icons and without icons

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am designing a form with  drop downs. I put an icon near start time. Start time and end time are on the same line for large screen and on 2 separate lines for a mobile device. However, the components are not lining up properly. For mobile, I want end time drop down, duration, and save button to each be on their own line and  **to be under** (and flush with) the start time drop down, **not** under the start time icon.
For large screen, I want duration and save button to be aligned with start time drop down, not the icon.

Any help is appreciated. code and screenshots below.

App.vue:

```
<template>
<div id="app">

<v-app id="inspire"> 

<Header/> 
<v-content>
<v-container fluid>
  <router-view></router-view>
</v-container>
</v-content>



 </v-app> 
 </div>
</template>
```

Session.vue:

```
      <template>
      <div id = 'newSession'> 


        <v-layout align-center justify-center >
      <v-flex xs18 sm10 md8>



      <div>
          <fieldset> 
              <legend align="left">Add New Session</legend> 

            <v-alert
              :value="invalidStartTimeorEndTime"
              type="warning"  
            >
              Start Time or End Time is invalid.
            </v-alert>


      <form @submit.prevent="submit">

            <v-layout row align-baseline>

            <!--menu allows the date-picker to show and not show -->
            <v-menu   
              ref="menu2"
              :close-on-content-click="false"
              v-model="menu2"
              :nudge-right="40"
              :return-value.sync="date"
              lazy
              transition="scale-transition"
              offset-y
              full-width
              min-width="290px"
            > 
              <v-text-field
                slot="activator"
                v-model="date"
                label="Session Date"
                prepend-icon="event"
                box
                readonly

              ></v-text-field>

            <v-date-picker v-model="date" @input="$refs.menu2.save(date)"  ></v-date-picker>

          </v-menu> 

          <label  color="indigo" background-color= "indigo" text-color="white"> {{getWeekendDate}} </label> <!-- colors x working -->

          </v-layout>


          <v-layout v-bind="binding">        

              <!-- <v-layout row> -->
              <!-- <v-icon>access_time</v-icon> -->


              <v-select
                :items="times"
                v-model="start_time"
                label="Start Time"
                prepend-icon="access_time"
                box
                placeholder="Start Time"
                ></v-select>


              <v-select
                :items="times"
                :value="getEndTime"
                label="End Time"
                box
                placeholder="End Time"
                @change="changeEndTime"          
              ></v-select>

              </v-layout>

              <v-layout column align-left >


                <div class="flex">

              <label>{{getDuration}}</label>

              <v-btn color="indigo" type ="submit" dark>Save</v-btn>

              </div>

              </v-layout>




      </form>

          </fieldset>
          </div>


          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>

      </div>

      </template>
```

[image: large screen - mostly aligned]
[image: mobile not aligned]

Comment: You could fake it I guess by putting `prepend-icon=" "`, not sure if that would have any side effects?

Comment: @Traxo - Thanks! The end time is now aligned! Duration label and Save button are still not perfectly aligned.

Comment: You could just tweak it by CSS depending in your preference. You can also wrap it in `<v-flex>` and margin class like `ml-4` just like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBxMzW?&editors=101

Comment: @gil - Thanks! The margin class helped for `duration` and `save button` - more aligned. The `<v-flex>` didn't help - just made the drop-downs look weird.